# How to detect a new device plugged in PC VB?

Tags: .net, vb.net, loops, device

I would to know if it is possible to read when a device is connected to the pc (is not important if it is a usb storage or device or something else). I tried a bit, but I did not find anything. Someone can tell me how to do that? I would like to create something that understands when a device is inserted (maybe with a loop in background) and in case it is inserted it performs a specific action. I'm using VisualBasic .NET 4.5.2 (i can use what .NET version i want).

Comment: hope [this](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/230820-read-device-manager-programatically#post944500) helps

Comment: [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31749/Device-Information) is better...:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WMI to raise an event when a storage device is plugged into the computer

```
'set a reference to system management 
 Imports System.Management
 Public Class Form1
     Private WithEvents w As ManagementEventWatcher
     Private q As WqlEventQuery
     Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       q = New WqlEventQuery("Select * from Win32_DeviceChangeEvent")
       w = New ManagementEventWatcher(q)
       w.Start()
    End Sub
   Private Sub w_EventArrived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Management.EventArrivedEventArgs) Handles w.EventArrived
       MessageBox.Show("Device Event", e.Context.ToString)
   End Sub
   Private Sub Form1_Closing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
        w.Stop()
    End Sub
 End Class
```

http://vb-tips.com/DeviceNotifyWMI.aspx

Comment: Thanks for answer but, i got an error on visual studio, it is not able to find ManagementEventWatcher class and WqlEventQuery class. How to solve it?

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operazione cross-thread non valida: è stato eseguito l'accesso al controllo 'Label1' da un thread diverso da quello da cui è stata eseguita la creazione.'

Solved previous problem, but now i got this, cross thread operation not valid, i try to modify label1.text when eventarrived

Comment: This is what i have, the problem is the same, error in cross-thread operation (button1.clicking)

`Private Sub w_EventArrived(sender As Object, e As EventArrivedEventArgs) Handles w.EventArrived
        w.Stop()
        Button1.PerformClick()
        q = New WqlEventQuery("Select * from Win32_DeviceChangeEvent")
        w = New ManagementEventWatcher(q)
        w.Start()
    End Sub`

Comment: Solved including a delegate